# Retrieving / Exporting Progress Chart of Windows File Processing

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-transfer, progress-bar

In newer window systems, a progress chart is shown when you process a large amount of files (transfer / copy, etc.). 
Is it possible to retrieve information of these graphs? Can it be done somehow? Is this information stored somewhere?
[Windows File Processing Progress Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpnvH.png)

Comment: Not stored anywhere, but that does not mean it cannot be done using software of some sort.